# Why confluence html macro not allow insert wiki markup

Tags: wiki, markup, confluence

I have a problem html macro.As I realized html macro does not allow insert wiki markup. For example - i need to insert link to user page. In wiki markup i'm type "[test|~test1]" and this is all. But this is not work in html macro. Maybe someone knows how to do it?
Thanks.
P.S. I'm use Confluence wiki version 4.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of confluence are you using?

If you need to have the link be in wiki-markup, instead of simply using an html link, but want the rest of the page to be in html, then you'll have to place the wiki-markup link outside of the html tags.

So it would look something like this:

```
{html}
<p>Insert your html content here</p>
{html}
{wiki-markup}
[test|~test1]
{wiki-markup}
{html}
<p>Insert the rest of your html content here</p>
{html}
```

Depending on which version of confluence you have, the way to insert this content in your editor might differ though.